# What is the difference between "generator" and "scaffolding"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What stuff does each one do (or, generate?) pardon the pun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scaffolding is generated by a generator.

Generators in general can generate many things, so you have to check the documentation for each.  Generators are run during the development process to create source code.

The scaffold generator can generate controller, model, and view files, as well as tests and migrations, depending on the options used.

Scaffolding are the default files created by the generator, which is just a quick and dirty implementation. Like building scaffolding, it is not intended to be the final thing, but just a stand in for the more polished version as you build it.